# Running Percentage in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a requirement to make a mtd pareto of defect. I have 4 columns needed: item, qty, share% and defect%. the defect% should be a cumulative percentage. Any help is very much appreciated. thank you.

```
defect% = itemqty/total volume qty
share%  = itemqty/total defect qty
```

(I would like to sum the share for the current row + share for the previous row.)

```
total defect itemqty  16
total volume itemqty  13
```

sample:
    item      itemqty    total volume qty

```
hardware  7 /16
Locked    5/16+sharepct of hardware
corroded  4/16+sharepct of locked
```

below is a sample data:

```
month       model  item       itemqty volumeqty
===============================================
2016(1) Jan  P6   Locked         1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   Locked         1      0
2016(1) Jan  P6   Locked         1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   Locked         1      1
2016(1) Jan  P5   Locked         1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   hardware       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   hardware       1      0
2016(1) Jan  P6   hardware       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   hardware       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P5   hardware       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P5   hardware       1      0
2016(1) Jan  P5   hardware       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   corroded       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   corroded       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P6   corroded       1      1
2016(1) Jan  P5   corroded       1      1
```

Comment: please update your question with the desired results. Without it it's difficult to clearly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar thread discusses cumulative sums and percentages here:

[Spotfire Custom Expression : Calculate (Num/Den) Percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305536/spotfire-custom-expression-calculate-num-den-percentages)

You are going to want to use something similar to:

```
Sum(If(trim([model])="P6",[itemqty])) then Sum([Value]) over (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows]))
```