# Spotfire Custom Expression : Calculate (Num/Den) Percentages

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am trying to plot Num/Den type percentages using OVER. But my thoughts does not appear to translate into spotfire custom expression syntax.

Sample Input:

```
RecordID  CustomerID  DOS       Age  Gender  Marker
9621854   854693      09/22/15  37   M       D
9732721   676557      09/18/15  65   M       D
9732700   676557      11/18/15  65   M       N
9777003   5514882     11/25/15  53   M       D
9853242   1753256     09/30/15  62   F       D
9826842   1260021     09/30/15  61   M       D
9897642   3375185     09/10/15  74   M       N
9949185   9076035     10/02/15  52   M       D
10088610  3512390     09/16/15  33   M       D
10120650  41598       10/11/15  67   F       N
9949185   9076035     10/02/15  52   M       D
10088610  3512390     09/16/15  33   M       D
10120650  41598       09/11/15  67   F       N
```

Expected Out:

```
Row Labels  D  Cumulative_D  N  Cumulative_N  Percentage
Sep         6  6             2  2             33.33%
Oct         2  8             1  3             37.50%
Nov         1  9             1  4             44.44%
```

My counts are working. 
I want to take the same Cumulative_N & Cumulative_D count and plot Percentage over [Axis.X] as a line chart.

Here's what I am using:

```
UniqueCount(If([Marker]="N",[CustomerID])) / UniqueCount(If([Marker]="D",[CustomerID])) THEN SUM([Value]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) as [CumulativePercent]
```

I understand `SUM([Value])` is not the way to go. But I don't know what to use instead.

Also tried the one below as well, but did not:

```
UniqueCount(If([Marker]="N",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) / UniqueCount(If([Marker]="D",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) as [CumulativePercent]
```

Can you have a look ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @Monte_fisto : I edit the original question to include sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks- can you add the data in text format?

Comment: How does that look ?

Comment: @niko : I did glance through all your Q&A's, but did not find anything that I could apply

Comment: Did 
(UniqueCount(If([Marker]="N",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows]))) / (UniqueCount(If([Marker]="D",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows]))) as [CumulativePercent]
Work?  That's the syntax I can get running.

Comment: @WeShall did the solution below work for you?

Comment: @scsimon i moved away from spotfire for few days after posting this, hence the radio silence. Will try out your solution & keep you posted. Thanks for letting me pick your brains.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work, but it may not fit your overall solution. I should mention i used `Count()` versus `UniqueCount()` so that the results would mirror your desired output.

1. Add a transformation to your current data table

   - Insert a calculated column `Month([DOS]) as [TheMonth]`
   - Set Row Identifers = `[TheMonth]`
   - Set value columns and aggregation methods to `Count([CustomerID])`
   - Set column titles to `[Marker]`
   - Leave the column name pattern as `%M(%V) for %C`

That will give you a new data table. Then, you can do your cumulative functions. I did them in a cross table to replicate your expected results. Insert a new cross table and set the values to:

```
Sum([D]), Sum([N]), Sum([D]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) as [Cumulative_D], 
Sum([N]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) as [Cumulative_N], 
Sum([N]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) / Sum([D]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) as [Percentage]
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Spotfire released a fix or based on everyone's inputs I could get the syntax right. But here is the solution that worked for me.

For Columns D & N,

```
COUNT([CustomerID])
```

[image]

For columns Cumulative_D & Cumulative_N,

```
Count([CustomerID]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) where [Axis.X] is DOS(Month), Marker
```

[image]

For column Percentage,

```
Count(If([Marker]="N",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) / Count(If([Marker]="D",[CustomerID])) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))
where [Axis.X] is DOS(Month)
```

[image]